# unit testing aws athena query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, boto3

```
import awswrangler as wr

def assume_role_and_query_athena(role_arn, query):
    # Assume the IAM role
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName='AssumedRoleSession'
    )
    
    # Extract the temporary credentials from the AssumeRole response
    credentials = assumed_role['Credentials']
    access_key = credentials['AccessKeyId']
    secret_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
    session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
    
    # Use the temporary credentials to execute the query in Athena
    wr.athena.connect(
        access_key=access_key,
        secret_key=secret_key,
        session_token=session_token,
        region='us-east-1'  # Replace with your desired AWS region
    )
    df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(query)
    
    return df
```

My question is how do we unit test the above code. I don't feel like there is much to unit test for. The core test needed is probably about being able to establish the connection which cannot really be unit tested.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write a unit test for connection and to ensure that function when given sample inputs has the expected outputs (DF and whatever pipeline should now be set up). Especially if you have it as a part of your more extended tests instead of in CI as you're right it might be a little much for CI.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example of how would you go about it if possible?